# How to switch 2 git accounts in Vscode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have 2 git accounts, 1 for my company git(default), another is my private github account. I have finished the settings, now I can git clone from my company git and github by git bash.
However, I couldn't git clone my repos(in github) by using CMD terminal in VScode,

```
"git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
```

now what should I do?

Comment: I find the solution: in .ssh folder, the file "config" is wrong, the file name is "config", not ".config"
But there is still another problem, git clone function works well in Terminal in Vscode, but  in vscode, "Shift+ctrl+P"-"Git : Clone" still not works.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem in 2 steps:

1. In .ssh folder, the file name "config" is wrong, the file name is "config", not ".config"
   After this step, git clone could be finished in Terminal in Vscode,but "Shift+ctrl+P"-"Git : Clone" still not works.
2. When I run the "ssh-gen" , I type the password but the password is different from the password of github.com, which leads to the vscode didn't git clone but terminal in vscode is OK.
   So I run the "ssh-gen" again and modify the windows credencials password of github.com.

Now, it's fixed